# SQL Sorting using Order by

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can you all please help me with this?

Presently, I have this SELECT which returns data ordered by this way

```
SELECT  DISTINCT gl.group_id,
        gl.group_name,
        gl.group_description,
        gl.status_code,
        gl.member_count,
        (
        SELECT  grpp.group_name
        FROM    test_group_relationship grel
        JOIN    test_group grpp
        ON      grel.parent_group_id = grpp.group_id
        WHERE   grel.child_group_id = gl.group_id
        ) AS parent_group_name,
        gl.group_name_key,
        gl.group_description_key
FROM    test_group gl
WHERE   gl.group_org_id = '3909'
        AND gl.group_name_key like '%' || 'GROUP' || '%'
ORDER BY
        gl.group_name_key, CONVERT(gl.group_name, 'WE8EBCDIC500')
```

The output is below.I have tried indenting the columns to paste the data.

```
GROUP_NAME                         GROUP_NAME_KEY

Add Group Basic Flow               ADD GROUP BASIC FLOW
Administrative Group               ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP
Amy Group 33                       AMY GROUP 33
Amy Test Group 1                   AMY TEST GROUP 1
another add group test from matt   ANOTHER ADD GROUP TEST FROM MATT
```

**My Question is in the FIELD GROUP_NAME--> how can i SORT DATA using ORDER BY 
so that lowercase letters will be sorted before uppercase letters.

Expected output is :-

the value "another add group test from matt" has to come at the first place.This way
lowercase letters are sorted first and then UPPER CASE.

---

See also:

- [SQL ORDER BY Issue Continued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805568/sql-order-by-issue-continued-please-help/807323)
- [PLSQL ORDER BY Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804110/plsql-order-by-issue)

Comment: Hi all,

Thanks a lot for your inputs.I am marking this question as answered  as my doubt is clarified.

Comment: I want to enter a other question but before that I want to make this query as answered so that everyone knows its completed.

Comment: I saw in your comments that you want to mark the question answered, but haven't.  All you have to do is click on the check mark next to your preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the type on the field to a collation that is case sensitive and order by it asc

In your order by add

Group_Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS Asc

assuming that your characters are in english; otherwise substitute french etc.

Answer (score 1):

try:

ORDER BY UPPER (SUBSTR (GROUP_NAME, 1, 1)), SUBSTR (GROUP_NAME, 1, 1) DESC, UPPER(GROUP_NAME), GROUP_NAME DESC;

Comment: I added your suggestion but its not working.

order by gl.group_name_key,UPPER (SUBSTR (GROUP_NAME, 1, 1)), SUBSTR (GROUP_NAME, 1, 1) DESC, UPPER(GROUP_NAME), GROUP_NAME DESC;


 In my SELECT-I wanted to work on the 2nd COLUMN in the order by clause which GROUP_NAME.

Comment: This works fine and so thanks a lot for the help.

Can you please tell me why is this needed "SUBSTR (GROUP_NAME, 1, 1) " and exactly what is that order by doing

Comment: basically you are just ordering the first digit of the string with all of them upper case.

Comment: These are the steps:

1. upper(first letter) -- to get all of the A's, B's, etc together
2. first letter, descending -- to put lower case letters before upper case
3. upper(the value) -- same as #1, but it applies to the 2nd letter too
4. the value, descending -- same as #2, but applies to the 2nd letter too

Answer (score 0):

Just add BINARY to your ORDER BY.

```
ORDER BY BINARY gl.group_name_key
```

You may have to use DESC otherwise upper case will come first. But then that would also sort z-a.

Comment: The issue is not with GROUP_NAME_KEY.

Group_name_key has values stored in CAPS and its fine.

I wanted to work on the 2nd COLUMN in the order by clause which
GROUP_NAME.

Comment: I used this order by BINARY gl.group_name_key,convert (gl.group_name, 'WE8EBCDIC500');

It gives an ERROR in ORACLE SQL -not able to identify the BINARY key word

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle guy, but depending on your version of Oracle, I believe that there are some session variables that will determine this for you. You can try the following:

ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp=binary;

ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort=GENERIC_M_CI;