# SQL ORDER BY issue

Tags: sql, plsql

Duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810599/order-by-with-decode-function-issue-with-multiple-columns), which itself cross-references 3 other minor variants of the same question.

---

Hi all,

I am sorry but i am putting my question as a new question in this post.I need all your help very much now and i appreciate your help very much

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT distinct gl.group_id,
                 gl.group_name,
                 gl.group_description,
                 gl.status_code,
                 gl.member_count,
                 (SELECT grpp.group_name
                      FROM test_group_relationship grel JOIN test_group grpp
                               ON grel.parent_group_id = grpp.group_id
                      WHERE grel.child_group_id = gl.group_id
                 ) AS parent_group_name,
                 gl.group_name_key,
                 gl.group_description_key
             FROM   test_group AS gl
             WHERE  gl.group_org_id   = '3909'
               AND (gl.group_name_key LIKE '%GROUP%')
         ) AS data_set 
    ORDER BY DECODE(:sort_key,
                      'name',            'constant',
                      'description',     group_description_key,
                      'memberCount',     LPAD(member_count, 4),
                      'status',          LPAD(status_code, 4),
                      'parentGroupName', parent_group_name
               )NULLS FIRST,
         UPPER(SUBSTR(group_name, 1, 1)),
         SUBSTR(group_name, 1, 1) DESC,
         UPPER(group_name),
         group_name DESC,
         group_name_key, 
         ;
```

My question still remains the similar.I want dynamic sorting to be done based on
the :sort_key variable which has one of the various options in the decode everytime to sort.

When,sort_key :='name'.As we can see it evaluates to a constant and then the remaining columns in the ORDER BY clause.

Now,when variable sort_key:= 'description' or 'memberCount'....each of the values,
then the ORDER BY LOGIC is different for each of them.

As an example,when 'description' is selected-the sorting in the ORDER BY cluase should do as it does for 'name'.

Example like this:-

```
 UPPER(SUBSTR(group_description, 1, 1)),
             SUBSTR(group_description, 1, 1) DESC,
             UPPER(group_description),
             group_description DESC,
             group_description_key,
```

In brief,each of the options that the sort_key variable gets-the ORDER BY logic is different and i have to implement it in the same SQL only now.

If its possible with order by CASE with all the options-can you please help me.I need your
help very much

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804110/plsql-order-by-issue which has various answers. unfortunately OP is unable to specify what is not working as desired other than "does not work" (see ref question and comments)

Comment: btw this is the 5th version of his question within 2 days

Comment: Hi all,

First of all-i apologize for this entire sequence of putting the same question and asking for solutions for the same question about 5 times changing it, but trust me,its been quite a struggle for me trying to do this query and in fact-without all your help wouldn't have go to know so many things.

I very much appreciate all your help earnestly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking if it is possible to vary the whole ORDER BY list dynamically based on a bound parameter, including ASC/DESC variations, etc.

Your best bet is to run different queries with different ORDER BYs depending on how you want to sort. It is much simpler and will run faster.

If you really want to do it the way you are asking, you can do it to a certain extent using the same technique you are already using with the ORDER BY DECODE(choice1, expression1, choice2, expression2,...), except that the expressions would have to be a lot more complex. Each expression would have to produce a concatenated string of fixed-size fields in order of sort priority, for example:

```
ORDER BY DECODE('description',     UPPER(SUBSTR(group_description, 1, 1))
                                || SUBSTR(group_description, 1, 1) 
                                || RPAD(UPPER(group_description),40)
                                || RPAD(group_description_key,10)

                ,'name',           UPPER(SUBSTR(group_name, 1, 1)),
                                || LPAD(1000-ASCII(group_name)), -- first char DESC
                                || RPAD(UPPER(group_name),20)
                                || RPAD(group_name_key,10)
```

Also, it would be difficult to mix ASC and DESC fields. You can switch direction for numeric fields using something like LPAD(1000000 - n,7) where the 1000000 is a number higher than any possible n. You can also play some other tricks like I did in my example with the first char of group_name.

This technique will prevent the database from using indexes to speed up the ordering (unless you add some crazy function-based indexes).

Again, I recommend you abandon this approach and just send the database a whole different query depending on your desired ORDER BY clause. If you are using PL/SQL, you can also use dynamic SQL to build the query with the desired ORDER BY clause and execute that.

EDIT: My PL/SQL is a little rusty but here is how you can do it in PL/SQL with dynamic SQL.

```
FUNCTION QueryGroups(sort_key in varchar2) RETURN REF CURSOR
IS
   sql_block VARCHAR2(2000);
   order_by VARCHAR2(2000);
   ret REF CURSOR;
BEGIN
   order_by :=
     CASE sort_key
       WHEN 'name'
         THEN  q'{UPPER(SUBSTR(group_name, 1, 1)),
                  SUBSTR(group_name, 1, 1) DESC,
                  UPPER(group_name),
                  group_name DESC,
                  group_name_key}';
       WHEN 'description'
         THEN  q'{UPPER(SUBSTR(group_description, 1, 1)),
                  SUBSTR(group_description, 1, 1) DESC,
                  UPPER(group_description),
                  group_description DESC,
                  group_description_key}';
     END CASE;

     sql_block = q'{SELECT *
                FROM (SELECT distinct gl.group_id,
                 gl.group_name,
                 gl.group_description,
                 gl.status_code,
                 gl.member_count,
                 (SELECT grpp.group_name
                      FROM test_group_relationship grel JOIN test_group grpp
                               ON grel.parent_group_id = grpp.group_id
                      WHERE grel.child_group_id = gl.group_id
                 ) AS parent_group_name,
                 gl.group_name_key,
                 gl.group_description_key
             FROM   test_group AS gl
             WHERE  gl.group_org_id   = '3909'
               AND (gl.group_name_key LIKE '%GROUP%')
         ) AS data_set }' || order_by;

     OPEN ret for sql_block;
     return ret;
END QueryGroups;
```

Comment: Thanks.I can understand your point in the above approach.

In addition,i was trying to do this using order by with CASE,but it does not run and gives 'keyword' missing error.

Comment: ORDER BY 
    CASE
  WHEN :p_sortby = 'name' THEN  UPPER(SUBSTR(group_name, 1, 1)),
                     SubSTR(group_name, 1, 1) DESC,UPPER(group_name), group_name_key, group_name DESC
 
/*The above THEN clause works if i just have only 1 argument after THEN .It doesn't work if i have all of the arguments*/
/*It gives a keyword missing error*/
 
I feel my syntax is wrong when we pass many arguments.Can you please correct me?

if i want to pass a DIFFERENT SQL by the value in the order by variable--how would i write it? Just one example of writing it will help me do the other ones

Comment: You can't do it like that. The thing after the THEN must be a single expression returning a single string. Same as the expressions in the DECODE. It cannot be a list of columns. Read my answer carefully. See how I concatenate using ||. But best of all, don't try to do it this way at all. Instead, build the query and its ORDER BY as a string and execute it using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks.But i am sorry i couldnt understand how to do this
"Instead, build the query and its ORDER BY as a string and execute it using dynamic SQL"

How can we build a SQL with order by as a string and run it using dynamic SQL?
I havent as such worked on writing dynamic SQLs till now and so your help in writing the QUERY would be very much helpful.

Once you write it,i will go through it to understand of how it is done specially for my case? Please help me,waiting for your answer

Comment: OK, I added an example in PL/SQL.

Comment: I am running this function but it gives a INVALID statement error.

What could be missing in this? I feel its because of some syntax issue in it.

Here,I am trying to the ORDER BY based on the vaule in sort_key variable.
I am not sure whats missing.Please help me